# Select different child JSON element with select input in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am printing a list of food types by making an API call per category. The food in the categories have this JSON structure:

```
{"uid":"56",
 "title":"Nussbrot",
 "code":"X 39 2000000",
 "final_factor":"0",
 "sorting":"0",
 "unit":[
   {"title":"Scheiben",
    "gram":"45",
    "max":"100"
   },
   {"title":"Messerspitzen",
    "gram":"250",
    "max":"12"}
   ]
  }
```

I am looping through & printing the values out into a template. No problem. I am printing the "unit" values into a select box:

```
  <option ng-repeat="title in food.unit">{{ title.title }}</option>
```

And I am currently printing out the grams & title of the first unit in each food like this:

```
<div class="max">Max is: {{ food.unit[0].max }}</div>
<div class="grams">Grams is: {{ food.unit[0].gram }} </div>
```

How can I make this dynamic, so that I am printing out the max & grams of the currently selected unit?

[Here's my Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/vd3v6cmc0suqyBpjzCzE?p=preview)

Comment: Did @dtabuenc answer your question? Looks like it to me but this one is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular makes dealing with options and selected options very easy. You should stop thinking in terms of indexes or value. With angular you can bind the entire object, so there's no need to look it up. For example you could do the following for your select:

```
<select ng-model='selectedUnit' ng-options="unit as unit.title for unit in food.unit"></select>
```

Let me briefly explain the expression for ng-options

- `unit in food.unit` means we will iterate over the `food.unit` array storing each value in `unit` as we go along.
- `unit as unit.title` means what we are putting in the ng-model whenever the user selects an item is the entire `unit` object itself. The `as unit.title` tells angular to use the title of the unit as a display for the option.

What this ends up doing is that whenever the user selects one of the options, the entire `unit` object will be stored in the ng-model variable (in this case `selectedUnit`). This makes it really easy to bind it elsewhere. For example you can just do:

```
<div class="unit">Unit is: {{ selectedUnit.title }}</div>
<div class="max">Max is: {{ selectedUnit.max }}</div>
<div class="grams">Grams is: {{ selectedUnit.gram }} </div>
```

In angular, if you find yourself dealing with indexes or ids and then looking things up by id or index then you are typically doing it wrong. One of the biggest advantages of using angular is how easy it is to deal with objects, and you should really take advantage of it.

For example, I often see newbies doing something like

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.name} <a ng-click="savePerson(person.id)">Save</a></li>
```

And then in their code they use the id to look up the person from an array:

```
$scope.savePerson = function(id){
   var person = persons[id];
   $http.post('/persons/'+id, person);
};
```

This kind of lookup is almost always unecessary with angular. You can almost alway just pass the person right away:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.name} <a ng-click="savePerson(person)">Save</a></li>
```

And then have the click handler take the person:

```
$scope.savePerson = function(person){
   $http.post('/persons/'+person.id, person);
};
```

I know I strayed a bit from your original question. But hopefully this makes sense and helps you write things more simply using the "angular way"

Her is the plunkr for your example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lEaLPBZNn0ombUe3GPa9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you can fist of all handle the selected item with the ng-selected:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSelected

```
<select>    
<option ng-repeat="title in food.unit" ng-selected="selectedIndex=$index">{{ title.title }}</option>
</select>


<div class="max">Max is: {{ food.unit[selectedIndex].max }}</div>
<div class="grams">Grams is: {{ food.unit[selectedIndex].gram }} </div>
```

This should propably work ;) Havn't tryed it yet!

Comment: No, $index is always set to 0 if I do this.

Comment: You don't need to mess with indexes or lookups from an array. See my answer for more info.